# Reading out single elements from a struct of an other contract

Tags: solidity, remix, dapps, mapping, struct

here a shortcut from my both contracts. Is it possible to read out and change single elements(from contract B) of the struct (Contract A) ? e.g. from contract B like p.submission(_id).studentaddress ? Or is it still the case that a struct is an internal element. What could be a way to read out and change elemtens from contract A from an other contract ?

Contract A:

```
  uint public SubCount = 0; 
struct Submission {
    uint id;
    address studentsaddress;
    Student student;
    Examiner examiner;
    Thesis thesis;
    // examniner accepts allocation
    bool accepted;
    // examiner finished correction
    bool corrected;
    // examiner marks submission as verified
    bool verified;
}

 // save submission in mapping with id as key
mapping(uint => Submission) public submissions;
   function createSubmission(address _studentsaddress,Student memory _student, Examiner memory _examiner, Thesis memory _thesis) public{
    SubCount ++; 
    submissions[SubCount] = Submission(SubCount,_studentsaddress, _student, _examiner, _thesis, false, false, false); 
    emit SubmissionCreated(SubCount, _studentsaddress, _student, _examiner, _thesis, false, false, false);
```

Contract B:

```
Submission p;                          
function setp(address _addr) external {
    p = Submission(_addr);
}

function readSubmission(uint _u) public returns(uint id, address studentsaddress, Student memory student, Examiner memory examiner, Thesis memory thesis, bool accepted, bool corrected, bool verified){
        return(p.submissions(_u)); 
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot access the storage of a contract from another contract directly. Given contracts C1 and C2, C1 can only access the storage of C2 by invoking a method on C2 that returns data from C2's storage. You can use the following ways to accomplish this:

1. Inherit contract A in B and then call contract's A method .
2. Add a function in contract A that updates the address of a student. First deploy contract A and then use the address of the deployed contract by passing this address to setAddressA function. Afterwards use setp to access the changeAddress function inside contract A from contract B. See my example below:

**Contract A**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;

contract A{
    uint public SubCount = 0; 
    event SubmissionCreated(uint, address,bool,bool,bool);
    
    struct Submission {
        uint id;
        address studentsaddress;
         //  Student student;
         //   Examiner examiner;
         //   Thesis thesis;
        // examniner accepts allocation
        bool accepted;
        // examiner finished correction
        bool corrected;
        // examiner marks submission as verified
        bool verified;
    }

     // save submission in mapping with id as key
    mapping(uint => Submission) public submissions;

   function createSubmission(address _studentsaddress) public{
        SubCount ++; 
        submissions[SubCount] = Submission(SubCount,_studentsaddress, false, false, false); 
        emit SubmissionCreated(SubCount, _studentsaddress, false, false, false);
   }
   
   function changeAddress(uint _studentid, address _address) external {
       submissions[_studentid].studentsaddress=_address;
   }
}
```

**Contract B**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;
import "./A.sol";

contract B {

    address addressA;
    
    function setAddressA(address _addressA) external{
        addressA = _addressA;
    }
    
    function setp(uint studentid,  address _newStudentAddress) external {
        A a = A(addressA);
        
        a.changeAddress(studentid,_newStudentAddress);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer ! Is there also an other way to do it ?

Comment: @Marc Yes! I have updated my answer.